# players support personnel

Tags: nouns

When a noun relates to a large number of people then it is used in plural

Example--

**Human Rights** Organisation

**Men's** parlor

But ICC Code of Conduct For Players and **Player Support Personnel**
is correct.

Support personnel relates to a large number of players not a single one so why is it not **Players support personnel**

Comment: I'm not convinced your basic premise (the first sentence above) is correct. But it's not necessarily relevant to ***Player Support Personnel***. In that collocation, the "root" noun is ***personnel***, which is modified by two singular "noun adjuncts" (used adjectivally, to identify the type of personnel, and within that the type of support). Same as, for example, ***town street map*** or ***car radio aerial***.

Comment: Then in men's parlour root word is parlour so could it be written man parlour??

Comment: No - but that's partly because ***men's parlour*** is neither a concept nor a collocation that would mean anything to most native Anglophones. It's quite natural to say, for example, *It's a man thing* (to explain why some guy acts or thinks the way he does). But there are no absolute rules here. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct) on **noun adjunct or attributive noun or noun (pre)modifier** *- traditionally mostly singular (e.g. "trouser press") except when there were lexical restrictions (e.g. "arms race"), but there is a recent trend towards more use of plural ones.*